# Why Material-UI Textfield does not accept type and maxlength same time?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI with React and TypeScript.

```js
<TextField
  id='user-id'
  label='user id'
  type='number'
  required
  helperText='Required'
  inputProps={{ maxLength : 12 }}
  onChange={(e) => setUserid(Number(e.target.value))}
  variant='filled' />
```

if I use `type` attribute with `inputProps`, it does not limit max length. I don't see any error message. I don't see where I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple approach I used for Marerial UI:

For **Typescript** you need to explicitly tell TypeScript the type of the `HTMLElement` which is your target.

```
<TextField
  id='user-id'
  label='user id'
  type='number'
  required
  helperText='Required'
  onInput={(e) => {(e.target as HTMLInputElement).value = Math.max(0, parseInt((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)).toString().slice(0, 12)}} 
  variant='filled' />
```

This will let TypeScript know that the element is a `number` and it will know of the value property.

You don't need `onChange` or `inputProps` here.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will not work for a number but will work for a String.
See this issue if similar to yours: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5309

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
const inputP = {maxLength: 30}

<TextField
  id='user-id'
  label='user id'
  type='number'
  required
  helperText='Required'
  inputProps={inputP}
  onChange={(e) => setUserid(Number(e.target.value))}
  variant='filled' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `maxlength` isn't a valid attribute for `<input type="number" />` you should use `max` instead.

```
<TextField
  ...
  type="number"
  inputProps={{
    max: <YOUR MAXLENGTH HERE>,
  }}
/>
```

[See this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5309).

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmax), you should use `max` (used for `numeric types`) instead of `maxLength` (used for `password, search, tel, text, url`):

```
<TextField
  id='user-id'
  label='user id'
  type='number'
  required
  helperText='Required'
  inputProps={{ max: 12 }}
  onChange={(e) => setUserid(Number(e.target.value))}
  variant='filled' />
```